# Java (Spring MVC) и сервис для ведения блогов

Tags: java, spring

Или я плохой пользователь ПК или я переискал очень много материала, чтобы найти адекватный ответ на вопрос, как же в джава проекте на спринге ввести систему блогов.
Пример: есть сайт, который предлагает услуги ордеринга меню, и на этом сайте, администраторы самых заведений хотят иметь возможность вести свои блоги в которых они могут сообщать об обновлениях и разных акциях, которые будут происходить в их заведениях. 
Вопрос: как правильно это сделать? 
Каждый блог должен иметь свою колонку в базе ? Должна быть таблица для блогов? Весь текст, а это огромное количество символов, где он должен сохраняться? В базе? Тогда какой тип поля должен быть, если к примеру используется база Postgres.

Comment: Вы спрашиваете про БД, но вините в проблеме spring. Вы явно не понимаете чего хотите. PS. проектирование БД и вообще архитектуры вашего приложения, обычно тут не спрашивают.

Comment: Сформулируйте себе краткое ТЗ по пунктам. Если уже имеется какое-то существующее приложение и хостинг - от них и отталкивайтесь. Например, требуется написание сайта для ведения блогов. Для авторизации пользователей сайт должен интегрироваться с существующей БД X, развернутой на Y. Запись в блоге должна поддерживать добавление комментариев, рейтинг и тд и тп. Потом, если не испугаетесь, перейдете к выбору технологии. Сейчас у вас каша в голове.

Comment: это правда, что каша, но вот я как-то стараюсь ее упорядочить

Comment: Как тут и сказали спринг и джава  не относится к вопросу. Вам нужно продумать структуру БД. Как все это будет храниться. А вот на каком языке реализовывать разницы нет.

Comment: @MrGarison но все это количество текста таки хранится в базе как я понял?

Comment: @Khodan.D. В базе. А где еще все это хранить? Да, хранить в базе каждую статью.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите видеоуроки [Jiri Pinkas'a](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLmcxdcWPhFqMq2BctGktOcIJKUw23wJeh) на английском. Там он создает блог на Spring. Также есть исходный код на [GitHub](https://github.com/jirkapinkas/java-blog-aggregator) и живой [пример](http://www.topjavablogs.com/). После просмотра Вы сможете создать блог, который описали.

Comment: спасибо, помогло

Comment: меня в корни этот вод запутал. Этот пинкал понаписывал целую тонну кода, а что к чему толком не сказал. У него там такая параша творится, я то понимаю, что он человек с опытом и сделано все правильно, но как понять там дохренища разных вещей, таких как .. ай не важно. кароче кто не смотрел этого пинкаса, лучше не смотрите, а то еще хуже себе сделаете.

Comment: Если хотите толком понять, что к чему, читайте Spring 4 для профессионалов.